# Convert HTML resume to pdf without any change in template

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I tried to convert this html resume to pdf and print it but as you see there is a problem in template after changing. For example compare skills in both html version and pdf version.

This is Github repo of this project: https://github.com/xriley/DevResume-Theme
And this is a sample of HTML file: https://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/demo/devresume/

How can I fix it for ever?

I need this: https://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/DevResume-Sketch-Template-PDF-Preview.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1 - Without Coding:

You can select margins as `custom` from more settings to make changes for each page accordingly.

[image]

Then you can `drag` these blue dotted borders to adjust text based on your need.

As i have drag thelower border upward to make senior developer text to appear in next page.

[image]
[image]

---

## Solution 2 - With Coding:

Simply adjust margins for each page from solution 1.

Then by using the `@page` in your **`CSS`**. You can modify margins when printing a document. You can't change all CSS properties with @page. Only few properties such as margins while printing the page etc.

```
@page:first {         <-----  first here is refering to only First Page
 margin-left: 0.75cm;
 margin-top: 0.25cm;
 margin-bottom: 0.25cm;
 margin-right: 0.75cm;
}
```

If you want to apply margins on all page then simply do this:

```
@page { your margins values }
```

You can read more about [@page property here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page).

Comment: What about doing this by coding?

Comment: @AminGholami I have updated my answer see if that can help!

Comment: Can you help me with template too? For example compare "skill" part of html version with pdf version. It is not aside in pdf version.

Comment: see this: https://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/DevResume-Sketch-Template-PDF-Preview.pdf

Comment: The code will take some time to understand, but the most i can help is that you have to play with `devresume.css` file

Answer (score -2):

I find the simplest solution. Without any codding. You just have to deploy your resume like website for example in Netlify.
Than go to this website https://www.sejda.com/html-to-pdf
Put your link to yopur website where is you CV and convert to pdf.  You will see the result without any changes all will look the same like in your website